# Why the deuteron has no excited state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics

Even the Eigen value problem solution precisely predict nucleons can lie in 1s and 1d state with 96 and 4 percentage probability respectively. I am confused are both of these state are only ground state and how can we do have a two ground state.

Comment: what exactly is your model for the potential?